# Print csv input file into a table of columns/rows

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write a program that (among other things), prints an input file ('table1.txt') into the format seen below.

[image]

Where diff is the difference between the 3rd and 4th value of each line.

I think I have the basic idea figured out and I tried doing:

```
f = open("table1.txt",'r')

for aline in f:
    values = aline.split(',')
    print('Team:',values[0],', Points:',values[1],', Diff:',values[2]-values[3],'Goals:',values[2]) 

f.close()
```

But it results in a operand type error. I think I just have to change the way I iterate over the items in the file but I do not know how.

Comment: `values[2]-values[3]` values is a list of string.

Comment: If you change the question text, then the answer provided wont make sense to future readers. Create a new question if you have other issues than what you specified before

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should definitely use the `csv` module for this. It allows you to iterate through rows and values (essentially building a fancy "list of lists"). `csv` also has a `DictWriter` object that would work well to spit this data into a file, but actually displaying it is a little different. Let's look at building the csv first.

```
import csv
import operator

with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf,
     open('path/to/output.csv', 'wb') as outf:
    reader = sorted(csv.reader(inf), key=operator.itemgetter(1)
    # sort the original data by the `points` column

    header = ['Team', 'Points', 'Diff', 'Goals']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=header)

    writer.writeheader()  # writes in the fieldnames
    for row in reader:
        if not len(row) == 4:
            break  # This is probably not a useful row
        teamname, points, home_g, away_g = row
        writer.writerow({'Team': teamname,
                         'Points': points,
                         'Diff': home_g - away_g,
                         'Goals': "{:>2} : {:2}".format(home_g, away_g)
                         })
```

This should give you a csv file (at `path/to/output.csv`) that has the data in the format you requested. At this point it's pretty easy to just pull the data and run `print` statements to display it. We can use string templating to do this nicely.

```
import itertools

row_template = """\
{{0:{idx_length}}}{{<1:{teamname_length}}}{{>2:{point_length}}}{{>3:{diff_length}}}{{=4:{goals_length}}}"""

with open('path/to/output.csv') as inf:  # same filename we used before
    reader = csv.reader(inf)  # no need to sort it this time!
    pre_process, reader = itertools.tee(reader)
    # we need to get max lengths for each column to build our table, so
    # we will need to iterate through twice!
    columns = zip(*pre_process)  # this is magic
    col_widths = {k: len(max(col, key=len)) for k,col in zip(
        ['teamname_length', 'point_length', 'diff_length', 'goals_length'],
        columns)}
```

It's worth stopping here to look at this magic. I won't go too far into the `columns = zip(*pre_process)` magic idiom, other than noting that it turns rows of columns into columns of rows. In other words

```
zip(*[[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]])
```

becomes

```
     [[1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [3, 6, 9]]
```

after that we're just using a dictionary comprehension to build `{'team_length': value, 'point_length': ...}` etc that we can feed into our templater to make the field widths the right size.

#### But wait!

We also need `idx_length` in that dictionary! We can only calculate that by doing `len(rows) // 10`. Unfortunately we've exhausted our iterator and we don't have any more data. This calls for a redesign! I actually didn't plan this out well, but seeing how these things happen in the course of coding is good illustration.

```
import itertools

row_template = """\
{{0:{idx_length}}}{{<1:{teamname_length}}}{{>2:{point_length}}}{{>3:{diff_length}}}{{=4:{goals_length}}}"""

with open('path/to/output.csv') as inf:  # same filename we used before
    reader = csv.reader(inf)
    pre_process, reader = itertools.tee(reader)

    # fun with pre-processing for field length!
    columns = zip(*pre_process)

    keys = ['teamname_length', 'point_length', 'diff_length', 'goals_length']
    col_widths = {k:0 for k in keys}
    for key, column in zip(keys, columns):
        col_widths['idx_length'] = max([col_widths['idx_length'], len(column) // 10 + 1])
        col_widths[key] = max((col_widths[key],max([len(c) for c in column)))

    col_widths['idx_length'] += 1  # to account for the trailing period

    row_format = row_template.format(**col_widths)
    # puts those field widths in place

    header = next(reader)
    print(row_format("", *header))  # no number in the header!
    for idx, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):  # let's do it!
        print(row_format("{}.".format(idx), *row))
```

### Batteries (almost) included

But let's not forget that Python has an extensive selection of 3rd party modules. One does exactly what you need. [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) will take well-formed tabular data and spit out a pretty printed ascii table for it. Exactly what you're trying to do

Install it from pypi from command line

```
$ pip install tabulate
```

Then import in your display file and print.

```
import tabulate

with open('path/to/output.csv') as inf:
    print(tabulate(inf, headers="firstrow"))
```

Or skipping straight from input to print:

```
import csv
import operator
import tabulate

with open('path/to/file.txt') as inf:
    reader = sorted(csv.reader(inf), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    headers = next(reader)
    print(tabulate([(row[0], row[1], row[2]-row[3],
                     "{:>2} : {:2}".format(row[2], row[3])) for row in reader],
                   headers=headers))
```

Answer (score 2):

try casting values[2] and values[3] into int when performing subtraction:

`', Diff:', int(values[2])-int(values[3])`

Comment: Thanks. I initially did: ', Diff:', int(values[2]-values[3]) but yours works.

Comment: np.. if you do int(str - str) then you are casting the result of subtract operation to int.. which wont work because you can't subtract strings

Comment: Any tips on how I would print the csv into columns and rows format as seen above?

Comment: I would look into the standard csv package - you can iterate through the csv object that package creates and append cells to array elements, etc.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using `with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:` and enter everything four spaces indented underneath. That's a good habit to be in, and you won't have to do `f.close()`

Comment: Does it matter that the intended input file is a .txt and not a .csv?

Comment: Good question... I'm unsure, I'm going to try that now.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried, and the CSV module does not care if you load a txt file.

I would use the `with open ... as` method, since it's cleaner and you don't have to close f afterwards.

```
import csv

with open("importCSV.txt",'r') as f:
    rowReader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    #next(rowReader)  -use this if your txt file has a header strings as column names
    for values in rowReader:
        print'Team:',values[0],', Points:',values[1],', Diff:',int(values[2])-int(values[3]),'Goals:',values[2]
```

Comment: I'm not crazy, right? This doesn't remotely resemble his expected output

Comment: I didn't intend to solve it for him/her, I was trying to demonstrate how to use `with open .. as` and the CSV module. I didn't think SO was a place to get people to write your code.