# From csv to table-like file

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv in the following form:

```
SYSID,DATA,PERIOD_NAME,ORA,MIPS 
PROD,2016-11-02,PRIME,10,3459.48 
PROD,2016-11-02,PRIME,11,2837.16 
PROD,2016-11-02,PRIME,12,2624.15
```

and I would like to obtain in output something like this

```
SYSID    DATA          PERIOD_NAME  ORA    MIPS
PROD     2016-11-02    PRIME        10     3459.48
PROD     2016-11-02    PRIME        11     2837.16
PROD     2016-11-02    PRIME        12     2624.15
```

I have tried

```
import csv
inf = open('pathtofile\\out.csv')
reader=csv.reader(inf)
ofile  = open('pathtofile\\fuffa.txt', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

but gives me the following "unformatted table"

```
SYSID   DATA    PERIOD_NAME ORA MIPS
PROD    2016-11-02  PRIME   10  3459.48
PROD    2016-11-02  PRIME   11  2837.16
PROD    2016-11-02  PRIME   12  2624.15
```

I have looked around but I can not find something useful for my problem.
Any hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: does this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33243260/2451259 answer your question?

Comment: Thank you @maahl,  maybe it works but I think Martin's answer below is easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could roll your own column formatter as follows:

```
import csv

def write_cols(data):
    col_spacer = "   "      # added between columns
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    return [col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]


with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    rows = list(csv.reader(f_input))

    for row in write_cols(rows):
        f_output.write(row + '\n')
```

Giving you the following output file:

```
SYSID   DATA         PERIOD_NAME   ORA   MIPS    
PROD    2016-11-02   PRIME         10    3459.48 
PROD    2016-11-02   PRIME         11    2837.16 
PROD    2016-11-02   PRIME         12    2624.15
```

This calculates the largest width for all values in each column and then spaces entries accordingly.    Note, make sure all of the entries in the CSV file contain the same number of columns, for example no empty lines.

---

For this to work in Python 2.6, the script can be modified as follows:

```
import csv

def write_cols(data):
    col_spacer = "   "      # added between columns
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    return [col_spacer.join("{0:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]


with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
        rows = list(csv.reader(f_input))

        for row in write_cols(rows):
            f_output.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: Hi Martin, this code is perfectly working on Python 2.7 but is not working on 2.6. 
I am trying to adapt the code in order to run on 2.6 as well following hints here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589550/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-reading-writing-from-to-file and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587244/why-does-a-python-script-work-on-windows-and-not-in-linux but without succes. Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It needs a couple of tweaks to work in 2.6. I've added a version which I have tested in Python 2.6.6.

Comment: uhm still not working:
  File "format.py", line 19, in write_cols
    return [col_spacer.join("{0:<{width}}"...) for index, col in e                                                                                                      numerate(row)) for row in data]
  File "format.py", line 19, in <genexpr>
    return [col_spacer.join("{0:<{width}}"....) for index, col in e                                                                                                      numerate(row)) for row in data]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Which exact version of Python are you using? Can you try it in 2.6.6 ?

Comment: I am trying 2.6.6 on Red Hat

Comment: You could try using the old Python string formatting syntax, `return [col_spacer.join("%-*s" % (widths[index], col) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]`

Comment: Nope, same problem. I am going mad! I know it would be easier to upgrade Python but the situation is more complicated here :)

Comment: I suggest you `print rows` to make sure you are getting correctly formatted data to pass to the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128251/discussion-between-alessandro-blasetti-and-martin-evans).