# Why does a Python script work on Windows and not in Linux?

Tags: python, linux

I have from one side Windows 7 with Python 2.7.12 and on the other side Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 with Python 2.6.6.

I have a script that works fine on Windows but not on RHEL.

I receive the following syntax error:

```
with open('pathtofile', 'rb') as f_input, open('pathtofile', 'w') as f_output:
#                                       ^
```

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It may be caused by different versions of Python on the two systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('pathtofile', 'rb') as f_input, open('pathtofile', 'w') as f_output:
```

is not supported by Python 2.6. In that version you can only open one file in the `with` statement. Instead, you can do

```
with open('pathtofile', 'rb') as f_input:
    with open('pathtofile', 'w') as f_output:
```