# Problem when pasting Dataframe (Panda) into CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping

first and foremost, I am sorry for my bad usage of terms as I am fairly new to programming. I have a Dataframe and want to transform it into a CSV file (did that succesfully). My problem is, that all the data now lands in one row, although it was in the right order in my dataframe. How can I fix this?

[This is the list with my example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zgIs.png).

[This is how it comes out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKrWS.png)

But I want three seperate columns.

Comment: I should add, that master_list was created using data_dict

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.

Comment: You are creating a .CSV file which means values are separated by **commas**. Each DF row will be a different line with values separated by commas. This is exactly what you are getting. A CSV file is not a formatted table with aligned columns.

Comment: Thanks @user19077881. I was watching a video where someone did the same, but got the desired result. That is, why I am wondering.

Comment: If you want a formatted table displayed then see [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225630/print-csv-input-file-into-a-table-of-columns-rows) which suggests various approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The format of the above should be there; the dictionary must contain a key with a list that contains all the values. I hope this explains the problem you are having.
For more information about *pd.DataFrame*, check out the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here    
import pandas as pd

data = {'business_id':[4,5],
        'business_name':['1.Brown & Associates Law & 
         Title,PA','2.Nirvana Title'],
        'address':['405 North Reo St Ste 320Tampa, FL 33609','405 
         North Reo St Ste 320Tampa, FL 33609']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```